# How to create rss feeds in my gwt application

Tags: gwt, rss, rss-reader

I am developing an GWT application on eclipse and I want to publish rss feeds in my application that can be viewed in my application's pages
On googling i found [this](http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/create-your-own-simple-rss-feed) tutorial but I think this tutorial is for html web pages.
I have no idea how to achieve this.
Any help is appreciated any samples or any tutorial

Comment: Google the answer first before posting question

Comment: I googled for the answer but i was not able to find quality solution for my requirement so did i posted this question.

Comment: SO post your requirement correctly

Comment: Please post an update whether you were able to solve the problem. It is a nice practice to close the question if it gets solved either by choosing an answer or by posting your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not able to google relevant links . Lets try together how to GOOGLE that for YOU. We will then walk you through search in Stackoverflow to find this - [Building RSS with GWT on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277728/building-rss-with-gwt-on-client-side)

[image]

[image]